# How can I solve the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' error when creating a dataframe from a list in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, text-parsing

I am trying to create a dataframe from a list butI get error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

```py
def write_csv(listofdicts, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvFile:
        wr = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=listofdicts[0].keys())
        wr.writeheader()
        for el in listofdicts:
            wr.writerow(el)type here

users_list = create_dicts(total_users_nowar, total_users_z, get_subs = False)
write_csv(users_list, 'total_users_r_e1.csv')
users_list = create_dicts(total_users_nowar, total_users_z, get_subs = True)
write_csv(users_list, 'total_users_with_subs_everyone.csv')

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-70aef893aa9b> in <module>
      1 #users_list = create_dicts(total_users_nowar, total_users_z, get_subs = False)
      2 users_list = create_dicts(total_users_nowar, total_users_z, get_subs = False)
----> 3 write_csv(users_list, 'total_users_r_e1.csv')
      4 users_list = create_dicts(total_users_nowar, total_users_z, get_subs = True)
      5 write_csv(users_list, 'total_users_with_subs_everyone.csv')

<ipython-input-45-3ff341d6bc21> in write_csv(listofdicts, filename)
      1 def write_csv(listofdicts, filename):
      2     with open(filename, 'w') as csvFile:
----> 3         wr = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=listofdicts[0].keys())
      4         wr.writeheader()
      5         for el in listofdicts:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

in the comments, people asked several questions like what is creat_dicts.

```
def create_dict_for_user(user_id, cl, info, get_subs):
    subs_list = None
    if get_subs:
        if not info['is_closed']:
            subscriptions_list = vk.users.getSubscriptions(user_id=user_id,extended=0)
            subs_list = subscriptions_list['users']['items']+list(-np.array(subscriptions_list['groups']['items']))
        user = {'user_id': user_id, 'cl': cl, 'gender': None, 'age': None, 'country': None,
                    'city': None, 'political': None, 'life_views': None, 'people_views': None, 'religion': None,
                    'subscribtions': subs_list, 'education': 'no_info'}
        if info != []:
            if 'bdate' in info.keys():
                if len(info['bdate'])>5:
                    user['age'] = calculateAge(datetime.strptime(info['bdate'], '%d.%m.%Y'))
                if 'country' in info.keys():
                    user['country'] = info['country']['title']
                if 'sex' in info.keys():
                    user['gender'] = gender[info['sex']]
                if 'city' in info.keys():
                    user['city'] = info['city']['title']
                if 'schools' in info.keys():
                    user['education'] = 'only_school'
                    if info['schools']!=[]:
                        if 'university' in info.keys():
                            if info['university']!=[]:
                                user['education'] = 'school_and_uni'
                    else:
                        if 'university' in info.keys():
                            if info['university']!=[]:
                                user['education'] = 'only_uni'
                else:
                    if 'university' in info.keys():
                        user['education'] = 'only_uni'
                if 'personal' in info.keys():
                    if info['personal']!=[]:
                        if 'political' in info['personal'].keys():
                            if info['personal']['political']>0:
                                user['political'] = political_views[info['personal']['political']]
                        if 'life_main' in info['personal'].keys():
                            if info['personal']['life_main']>0:
                                user['life_views'] = life_views[info['personal']['life_main']]
                        if 'people_main' in info['personal'].keys():
                            if info['personal']['people_main']>0:
                                user['people_views'] = people_views[info['personal']['people_main']]
                        if 'religion' in info['personal'].keys():
                            religion = info['personal']['religion']
                            if religion in religion_list.keys():
                                user['religion'] = religion_list[religion]
                            else:
                                user['religion'] = 'Другое'
                                print(religion)
        return user

def create_dicts(users_nowar, users_z, get_subs = True):
    user_list = []
    startind = 0
    users_nowar_info = []
    while startind < len(users_nowar):
        stopind = min(startind+1000, len(users_nowar))
        users_nowar_info += vk.users.get(user_ids = users_nowar[startind:stopind], fields = ['bdate','city','country', 'personal','sex','education','schools'])
        startind = stopind
    startind = 0
    users_z_info = []
    while startind < len(users_z):
        stopind = min(startind+1000, len(users_z))
        users_z_info += vk.users.get(user_ids = users_z[startind:stopind], fields = ['bdate','city','country','personal',
                                                                                     'sex','education','schools'])
        startind = stopind
    for i in range(len(users_nowar)):
        clear_output(wait=True)
        print('nowar', i)
        try:
            user_list.append(create_dict_for_user(users_nowar[i], 'nowar', users_nowar_info[i], get_subs))
        except:
            pass
    for i in range(len(users_z)):
        clear_output(wait=True)
        print('z', i)
        try:
            user_list.append(create_dict_for_user(users_z[i], 'z', users_z_info[i], get_subs))
        except:
            pass
    return user_list
```

I am using VK API to assess the response of people to the special military operation in Ukraine. Users z are those who support the operation and users no war are those who are against the operation.

Comment: It's hard to tell since we don't know what `listofdicts[0]` is. Could you give some more information?

Comment: But, what is: `create_dicts()`? What is `total_users_nowar`? What is `total_users_z`?

Comment: `listofdicts[0]` is None.  It isn't a dict.  Show us how that list is created.

Comment: I think listofdicts[0] is the problem in my code and I don't how it was created before. listofdicts appeared first in write_csv function.

Comment: I think that the function: `create_dict_for_user()` may return `None`.

Comment: Yes, you have: `get_subs = False` which will cause `create_dict_for_user()` to return `None` which is then appended to `user_list`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue then? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No really. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with the code. Why do you have `get_subs = False`? This leads directly to the problem. What is the solution? Should you delete that line? Should the code in the functions do something else?